# Angular Material 2 configuration in webpack

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-webpack-starter

[using angular material 2 in webpack and the tab css is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcQwk.png)

[using angular material autocomplete and throws this error , and this error disappears if i remove the lazy loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCmaK.png)

Is there any configurations for webpack to make the material working properly?

Comment: a u using angular-cli? did u check that https://material.angular.io/guides ?

Comment: @Kuncevic I am using this starter webpack from github i have just cloned it and working on it... --> https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter      and I have referred that guide on material.angular.io/guides

Comment: For your second image, here's an issue which was similar to the error: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3176

Comment: And what version of `@angular/material` are you using?

Comment: @Edric I am using the version ^2.0.0-beta.2

Comment: @Edric how to overcome that second error of originX , I read that but what if I need to add that component in my production app, hw can i overcome it now..

Comment: @AyzPat Post your working plunkr here if you have it... it could be helpful. Have you screen scraped any of your relevant code? For people to compare... such as how you're providing the Material Module for each item you're needing to use on the Component and in the AppModule. What build system you're using may also be important... CLI? Seed? Webpack? Also, how are you getting the CSS into the app? Are you including it in the index.html, or what?

Comment: @Jarvis I am installing it through npm and using webpack , following the same code as in the angular material website for the components..